# Petest function in R

Tags: r, regression

How can I find the function 'petest' in R?

A little background, I want to compare two different #regressions, 
y=x1+x2
logy=logx1+logx2

It is clear to me that I cannot use the BIC or AIC values, because the outcome variable is different. I searched in verbeek 2008 (A guide to modern Econometrics) and he suggests the PE test to compare linear and loglinear models.

I searched on this website http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/lmtest/html/petest.html and there I could find that the PE test exist in R, however, I cannot find it. I have the package lmtest, and 'petest' is supposed to be there, but when I try to use it, it says: Error: could not find function "petest".

Also, I have looked for more explanation, like examples, or videos that show how to apply this PE model, but I did not find any. Any help on this topic is highly appreciated!

Comment: If you could supply a reproducible example of the failure--specifically, the way in which you "try to use it,"--then this question could be migrated to [SO].

Answer (score 1):

Your name tells me you might not be that familiar with R (correct me if I'm wrong). You will first need to install the needed package, see this link for how to: https://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-r-packages/

After installing, make sure you load the package by using

```
library(lmtest)
```

After you've loaded the needed package, you can use

```
?petest
```

to find the helpfile that corresponds to the function. Examples and applications of the function are found at the bottom of the helpfile.If after taking these steps you still can't open the helpfile, something has gone wrong with the loading of the library.